# Implement Exclusive Option in Multi-Select: clear other entries on selecting it, clear it on selecting others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a Multi-Select where one option must be exclusive:

1. If it gets selected, any other prior selections in the Multi-Select are deselected
2. If another option gets selected while it is selected, this option is deselected

I was trying to examine the just-selected option, but `.val()` gives me the overall selection.

```
$('#educationLevel').on('change', function(e) {
    var selection = $(e.target).val();
    // This gives overall selection, not the just-selected one for my checks
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: On a multi select `val()` returns an array. Check what's in the array

Comment: I can't. I need to know what has *just* been selected *individually*. I can't just say that if the array contains my value, then force it to my value. If that's the case, I'll never exit the exclusive-option condition. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I understand that you can either have only that one specific value or a combination of any of the others. Is that not correct?

Comment: That's correct. But if that one specific value is selected, I won't be able to select anything else afterwards, and I should be able to. That's why I can't ask "does my array include this value." Are you saying that the *order* of the items in the array can tell me the latest-added item?

Comment: Sure you can. You can splice the array and set the updated value of the select

Comment: Care to demonstrate with a snippet? Are you saying the order tells me which one is last-added?

Comment: Order shouldn't matter. You either have the exclusive value in the array or you don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar thread here, [Mutual exclusion for <option>s in a <select>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041660/mutual-exclusion-for-options-in-a-select) . We need to keep track of the **current** selection array and diff it with the **latest** selection array. This will tell us what has **just** been selected.

Solution:

```
// Global Var:
// To implement an exclusive option in a MultiSelect dropdown,
// we need to keep track of the current selection (a global var here) 
// and diff this array with the latest selection array in change() event.
var currSel = $('#educationLevel').val();

// Change Event Definition
$('#educationLevel').on('change', function() {
    var newSel = $(this).val();
    // Get diff from currSel; a 1-element array expected.
    // Diff in arrays: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034768/1005607
    var diff = newSel.filter(x => !currSel.includes(x));
    // If exclusive option just got selected, delete all others
    if (diff.length) {
        if (diff[0] === '405') { // '405' is my exclusive option
           // If exclusive option just got selected ("405"), deselect all others 
           // in modified selection array
           newSel = ['405'];
        } else {
           // If non-exclusive option just got selected, ensure that the exclusive option 
           // is not in the modified selection array
           newSel = newSel.filter(el => el !== '405');
        }
        // Set dropdown to the modified new selection array
        $('#educationLevel').val(newSel);
    }
    // Clone latest selection array into current selection array
    currSel = [...newSel];
}
```